# cómo se guarda en bash un archivo como csv cuando hay un bucle while

Tags: bash, csv

Tengo el siguiente script de bash

```
while IFS="," 
   read v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13; 
   do if [ -z "$v12" ]; 
      then echo "$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,'unknown',$v13"; 
   else echo "$v1, $v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,$v12,$v13"; 
   fi;
done 
>train3.csv
```

Con el, quiero hacer unas transformaciones sobre el dataset que muestro a continuación y guardarlo en un nuevo csv.

```
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
18,1,2,"Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene",male,,0,0,244373,13,,S
20,1,3,"Masselmani, Mrs. Fatima",female,,0,0,2649,7.225,,C
27,0,3,"Emir, Mr. Farred Chehab",male,,0,0,2631,7.225,,C
29,1,3,"O'Dwyer, Miss. Ellen ""Nellie""",female,,0,0,330959,7.8792,,Q
30,0,3,"Todoroff, Mr. Lalio",male,,0,0,349216,7.8958,,S
32,1,1,"Spencer, Mrs. William Augustus (Marie Eugenie)",female,,1,0,PC 17569,146.5208,B78,C
33,1,3,"Glynn, Miss. Mary Agatha",female,,0,0,335677,7.75,,Q
37,1,3,"Mamee, Mr. Hanna",male,,0,0,2677,7.2292,,C
43,0,3,"Kraeff, Mr. Theodor",male,,0,0,349253,7.8958,,C
46,0,3,"Rogers, Mr. William John",male,,0,0,S.C./A.4. 23567,8.05,,S
```

Con el código que planteo, se crea el csv pero vacío.
Haciendo `done >train3.csv` también devuelve un documento vacío.

Cómo puedo hacer que se guarde?
Debería incluirlo antes del `done`?

Gracias.

Comment: done >train3.csv  hace que el bucle lea el archivo train3.csv linea a linea. Si quisieras  imprimir  un nuevo csv podrias utilizar echo >>  "  $VARIABLES " y imprimirlo linea a linea.

Comment: @Eric pero cómo elijo el nombre del archivo y extensión?

Comment: @Eric, igualmente haciéndolo como me indicas no obtengo ningún resultado. No sale nada por pantalla y tampoco se crea un archivo CSV.

Comment: debes hacer `done < fichero_de_entrada > fichero_de_salida`

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', y si sólo puedo tener el archivo de entrada al hacer la invocación? No tengo claro que esta opción sea la mejor, pero por otra parte, tampoco veo otras alternativas...

Comment: si lees un fichero, escribir sobre él mismo seguramente te lo trunque, pues bash ejecuta `> fichero` lo primero de todo. Por tanto, lo recomendable es hacer `done < entrada > salida`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', no, me refiero a invocar ```file1.csv```, hacer los cambios y guardarlo en ```file2.csv```, pero la invocación es ```./script.sh < file1.csv``` y el script no contiene internamente una llamada al documento

Comment: Puedes invocarlo haciendo `./script.sh < entrada > salida`.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un archivo llamado `script.sh` con el siguiente contenido:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=","
   read v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13;
   do if [ -z "$v12" ];
      then echo "$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,'unknown',$v13";
   else echo "$v1, $v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,$v12,$v13";
   fi;
done < nuevo_archivo.csv
```

Y mi archivo llamado `nuevo_archivo.csv` contiene lo siguiente:

```
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
18,1,2,"Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene",male,,0,0,244373,13,,S
20,1,3,"Masselmani, Mrs. Fatima",female,,0,0,2649,7.225,,C
...
```

Para poner el procesado de mi script `script.sh` en un nuevo archivo, hago lo siguiente:

```
$ ./script.sh > train3.csv
```

Y adentro de ese archivo tengo como resultado:

```
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,'unknown',Q
18,1,2,"Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene",male,,0,0,244373,13,'unknown',S
20,1,3,"Masselmani, Mrs. Fatima",female,,0,0,2649,7.225,'unknown',C
```